# fail sending non-premitive param with angularjs stateParams

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this angular-js template:

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-align="center center">

    <div layout="column" flex="50">
        <div>search results</div>
        <md-card flex="60" ng-repeat="voice in $ctrl.voices" ng-click="$ctrl.editVoice($index)">
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>

...
```

I have this angular-js code:

```
app.component('voiceFormComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/voice-form.html',
        controller:  ['$state', '$stateParams', '$http',
            function ($state, $stateParams, $http) {

                var self = this;
                console.log("in voice prompt component");

                var isVoiceUndefined = $stateParams.voice === undefined;
```

when the template sends `onClick(1)` and there are 3 elements in "voices" array.

how come I always get `$stateParams.voice === undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must define all paramters in states config, then you can use i.e. $state.go('state', {param: anyObject})